# Order users by score in Firebase realtime database

Tags: c#, android, firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to order users by their highest scores to create a leaderboard, however, when trying to order them by the score, what I am getting is the users ordered in an alphabetical order.

Here is an image of the database structure: [database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrJSH.png)

This is my attempt at getting the ordered list of users:

```
List<User> list = new List<User>();
list = (await firebase.Child("Users").OrderBy("HighScore").LimitToLast(10).OnceAsync<User>()).Select(item => new User
    {
        Username = item.Object.Username,
        Password = item.Object.Password,
        HighScore = item.Object.HighScore
    }).ToList();
```

Here is the result of the query ref/Users/.json?orderBy="HighScore"&limitToLast=10:
**{"a":{"HighScore":500,"Password":"a","Username":"a"},"ac":{"HighScore":0,"Password":"ac","Username":"ac"},"b":{"HighScore":1100,"Password":"b","Username":"b"}}**

And here are the database rules: [rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lx4hx.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that my query **does** return the 10 users with the highest score. But for some reason the list my code gives is ordered alphabetically based on the username and not based on the score field. So what I did was sorting the list after I got the list of the 10 best users `List<User> orderedList = list.OrderByDescending(o => o.HighScore).ToList();`

Now it seems to work the way I intended it.